# How do I clone an element or chunk of dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, tree, d3.js

I have been trying to create a beautiful tree with D3.

And for the nodes I have a SVG "template" in a hidden div. But I have been trying with many functions of D3 to "clone" the "template" but all didn't run.

The last javascript code is:

```
...
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("transform",
                    function(d)
                    {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    }
            );

var template_box = d3.select("#layer1");
console.log(template_box);

node.insert(template_box);
...
```

And the chuck of html is:

```
...
    <body>
 <svg width="400" height="400">
 <g
 id="layer1"
 transform="translate(-208.375,-410.5)">
<rect
...
```

Regards.

Comment: See [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to define some shapes up front and then reuse them at different positions in the diagram, you are going to have better results with svg's `<defs>` and `<use>`. See [this simple example](http://www.svgbasics.com/defs.html) for background. You can create your shape up front like this:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400">
 <defs>
   <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-208.375,-410.5)">
     <rect
     ...
```

Then instead of trying to clone the **content** of the `<g>`, you simply refer back to it's **definition**. So your code would be something like this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; } )

node.append("use")
  .attr("xlink:href","#layer1")
```

Note that the xlink namespace in the svg definition is important.

**UPDATE:** Here is a full working example of the above approach:

http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/5988971

Comment: Not a clone as you cannot change the elements in #layer1 using "use"