# How can I clone and modify an existing group into a selection?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an existing SVG with a complex group template. I want to reuse and multiply it in the context of some data (`selection.data().enter()`)

```
<svg>
<g id="template">
  *** complex inner ***
</g>
</svg>
```

I want to clone this #template with D3 according to some data, but I want to modify each clone according to the data:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll('g')
        .data(['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'lime']).enter()
        .append(***A CLONE OF MY TEMPLATE****)
        .select(***SOMETHING IN MY COMPLEX INNER***)
        .attr('fill', function(d){return d;})
```

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XQcw8/2/) is a fiddle that multiplies the clones with the data, but I cannot modify the fill color of the first rectangle, for instance

The `<use>` tag is not useful because it refers element, but you cannot modify inner elements without modifying all the instances like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573896/how-do-i-clone-an-element-or-chunk-of-dom)

In fact I want to do the same as in [this proposal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGParamPrimer-20090616/) with D3.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to a problem I have often run into with getting elements to inherit data from a parent node. The solution is hidden in Mike Bokstock's [article on selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data). The key is that data can passed from parent to child by using insert, append, or select. Note that using selectAll does not pass the data to the child.

In your case, you just need to change

`.selectAll("#fillPart").attr('fill', function(d){return 'red'})`

to

`.select("#fillPart").attr('fill', function(d){return d})`

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5LV7U/) is an updated fiddle with the change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `selectAll` to select the `fillPart` while you're already selecting all `.instance`s, thereby creating a nested selection, which is not what you want.

Also, since you are cloning the element, you don't want to have an `id` inside it, because then you will have multiple elements with the same id. Start by changing `id="fillPart"` to `class="fillPart"`.

When you select all `.instance` elements, the methods you call on the selection will be applied to *each* element in the selection once, therefore instead of calling `selectAll('.fillPart')`, which would select all fillPart elements within *each* instance, you just want to call `select('.fillPart')` to select the single fillPart that is attached to the current instance.

Having done that, you can now just assign the fill color based on the data:

```
.select(".fillPart")
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return d; });
```

Now you should get the desired result. Here's the updated [**JSFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ST8C7/).